# java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have my app which gives the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.svpino.longhorn/com.appc.longhorn.activities.DashboardActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
```

When I run the app in Android 4.3 it works fine and everything loads correctly. However on version 4.4.2 it crashes. Furthermore on my Galaxy note 3 on CM 4.4.2 it works fine.

My question is this device dependent error ? From the stacktrace it does not look like it.

My XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/stockListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.appc.longhorn.fragments.StockListFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the main activity

```
public class DashboardActivity extends FragmentActivity implements StockListFragmentCallback, StockQuoteCollectorObserver {

private final static String LOG_TAG = DashboardActivity.class.getName();

private BackStack backStack;
private Dialog searchDialog;
private Dialog noConnectivityDialog;
private Dialog termsAndConditionsDialog;
private StockListFragment stockListFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Extensions.isPriorHoneycomb()) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
```

Comment: Try to change `android:class` with `android:name` and retest.

Comment: No Still returns the same error. Line 24 is <fragment

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nFvhmeam

Comment: You need to look on this error:
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at com.svpino.longhorn.artifacts.StockTileProcessor.createFixedHeaderRow(StockTileProcessor.java:119)

there is something wrong in your StockTileProcessor on line 119

Comment: Maybe it's related to your `StockTileProcessor` which has an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. It seems that something is wrong in an array.

Comment: View tile1 = createTile(fragment, stocks.get(0), 0, false);
   View tile2 = createTile(fragment, stocks.get(1), 1, false);
   View tile3 = createTile(fragment, stocks.get(2), 2, false);

Comment: This code however works on multiple other devices ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an **IndexOutOfBounds** Exception

> `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size
>   is 0
>               at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>               at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>               at         com.svpino.longhorn.artifacts.StockTileProcessor.createFixedHeaderRow(StockTileProcessor.java:119)`

suggest you look at line 119 in **StockTileProcessor** class

Comment: Here is my line 119   View tile1 = createTile(fragment, stocks.get(0), 0, false);
   View tile2 = createTile(fragment, stocks.get(1), 1, false);
   View tile3 = createTile(fragment, stocks.get(2), 2, false);

Comment: You have so much of stuff in one line? Anyway, I suspect there's nothing in the list `stocks` and you're trying to get the first element in `stocks.get(0)` without checking if its `empty()`. Or only 2 items thats why `stocks.get(2)` is throwing an exception.

Comment: Sorry those were the next three lines. Let me validate by adding a null statement